# How can I call a function to main class that has a parameter?

Tags: c#, function, parameters

I have a function that name is Mymethod. It has three paramaters. I want to call it in Page_Load():
My question is what i should write to call MyMethod function with parameters.

```
public static string MyMethod(string Pro_id, string Sta_id, string Ity_id)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNECTION_STRING);
        con.Open();
        String UserId = HttpContext.Current.Session["user_id"].ToString();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO issue values ('" + UserId + "','" + Pro_id + "','" + Sta_id + "','" + Ity_id + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        return "error";
    }
    return "success";
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i wrote "MyMethod(string Pro_id, string Sta_id, string Ity_id);" in Page_load but i have error.

Comment: What error you are getting.. Posting incomplete questions wont get you an answer

Comment: My question is what i should write to call MyMethod function with parameters.

Comment: And our question is what error you are getting

Comment: it is not using like my code.It says this.

Comment: thank you i understood how it calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call your method like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string pro_id="xxx";//you need to assign it or retrieve somewhere
   string sta_id="xxx";//you need to assign it or retrieve somewhere
   string ity_id="xxx";//you need to assign it or retrieve somewhere

  MyMethod(pro_id, sta_id, ity_id);
 }
```

When you call a method you don't have to write the type of the parameter. Just write the name of the variable who has the same type as the parameter.in your cas `string`